# ActiveMQ, JavaScrtipt Paho.MQTT durable subscriptions

Tags: javascript, mqtt, activemq-classic, paho

ActiveMQ Classic v5.17.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Using command line tools I can successfully create a Durable Subscription, the ActiveMQ console shows the Active Durable Topic Subscriber.

```
npx mqtt sub --no-clean -i DAVE --qos 1 --verbose -t "mytopic"
```

Using the Paho.MQTT libraries I attempt to subscribe from an JavaScript client, in a browser, using MQTT over WebSockets. The subscription is successful, but is not durable. The ActiveMQ console shows an Active non-durable topic subscriber.

```
let client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", 61614, "DAVID");
client.connect(
    {
      onSuccess: onConnect,
      cleanSession : false
    }
);

function onConnect() {
    let QOS = 1;
    // quality of service passed in options object
    client.subscribe("mytopic", { qos: QOS} );
}
```

Advice please.

Edited in response to Brit's comment.The QOS value should be passed in an options object, I have adjusted the code as shown. However I still do not
see a durable subscription.

Using a debugger I can see the cleanSession flag being interpreted correctly. Using an onSubscribe callback I can see the QOS being granted.

Comment: Subscribe with `client.subscribe("mytopic", { qos: QOS});`

Comment: @Brits thanks, I should indeed by passing an options object, however even with this fix I still get a non-durable subscription,